# How to toggle 'className' dynamically in react.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to set the `active` class dynamically in react.js but it's not working!
I'm using the `setState()` method to change the selected item.

this line of code not work .
`className={selectedCategoryId === item.id ? 'active' : ''}`

I think the `setState()` function does not work correctly...

```
const {open, selectedProduct, productCategory, filteredProducts, selectedCategoryId} = this.state;
const categoryItems = productCategory.map((item) =>
    <a key={item.id}
       onClick={() => this.handleFilter(item.id)}
       className={selectedCategoryId === item.id ? 'active' : ''}
       // className={()=>this.isActive(item.id)}
       className="pointer"
    >{item.value}</a>
);
```

this does not change the class:

```
handleFilter = (id) => {
    const filteredItem = this.state.productList.filter(x => x.categoryId == id);
    this.setState({filteredProducts: filteredItem, selectedCategoryId: id});  
}
```

but this change the className correctly when select I all tags:

```
handleRemoveFilter = () => {
    this.setState({filteredProducts: this.state.productList, selectedCategoryId: 0});
}
//-------------------------------
<div className="tag-list">
    <a  onClick={this.handleRemoveFilter}
        className="pointer"
        className={ this.state.selectedCategoryId === 0 ? 'active' : ''}
    >All tags</a>
    {categoryItems}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I want to help but I didn't really understand the problem. Please try to be clear about what you EXPECT to happen and what IS happening.

Comment: please put here relevant code frok and show us link(it will be easier to help you):https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pzyyha

Comment: Why did you use "className" twice ?

Comment: Can you share the whole component?

Comment: I Really didn't thinks that made the problem! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If setState() works well, try this :

```js
<a onClick={this.handleRemoveFilter}
        className={ this.state.selectedCategoryId === 0 ? 'pointer active' : 'pointer'}
>All tags</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common ways is to use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) which you can conditionally joining classNames together

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

class Button extends React.Component {
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
      btn: true,
      'btn-pressed': this.state.isPressed,
      'btn-over': !this.state.isPressed && this.state.isHovered
    });
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: i wanna set className dynamically but `className={selectedCategoryId === item.id ? 'active' : ''}` not work .

Comment: The correct way to write is `className={classNames({active: selectedCategoryId === item.id})}`

Answer (score 1):

We can toggle class name dynamically like below,

```
const [islight, setIslight] = useState(false)
const toggle = () => {
    setIslight(!islight)
}

return (
   <div className={`block ${islight ? "blocklight" : "blockdark"}`}>
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

store classname in state along with selected item. You can just update the classname in state whenever required.

for eg,

```
  <a key={item.id}
            onClick={() => this.handleFilter(item.id)}
            className={this.state.activeClassName}
```

where active classname can be updated inside handlefilter